# How to stream a data stream to client from Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, streaming

My Node.js server receives a stream of data from an external API.
I serve my client after receiving the data completely. Like this,

```js
async function getFile(req, res) {
    const { id } = req.body;
    const file = await get(process.env.FILE_API_URL + id);

    res.send(file);
}
```

But instead of waiting to receive the whole stream, I would like to stream it to the client as soon as I have some data. Kind of like this,

```js
function getFile(req, res) {
    const { id } = req.body;
    const stream = get(process.env.FILE_API_URL + id);

    stream.on('data', (data) > {
        res.write(data);
    });

    stream.on('end', res.end);
}
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Does the external API already support streaming? Otherwise, you cannot do much better than wait for the data.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen yes, it does. It streams the data to my server.

Comment: How? Using the HTTP protocol?

Comment: `node-fetch`, `axios`, `got`, and node built-ins all support streaming the result from an HTTP request. The question should be updated with more details to qualify for a response. Which library do you use? Please include a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: Sorry. The question seems dumb now. I used Node.js's built-in https module to solve it.